# Setting one object array from values in 2 other object arrays

Tags: c#, .net-5

I am trying to set the Object3's array to some of the values that exist in Obect1's array and Object2's array.

My dto's:

```
    public partial class Class1
    {
        public ObjectType1[] ObjectType1 { get; set; }
        
        public ObjectType2[] ObjectType2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjectType1
    {
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string GroupDescription { get; set; }
        public string Quality { get; set; }
        public string QualityDescription { get; set; }
        public string QualityStatement { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjectType2
    {
        public string CharId { get; set; }
        public string CharNumber { get; set; }
        public string Grid { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Quality{ get; set; }
    }
```

My model :

```
    public partial class ValidationResultDto
    {
        public Object3[] Object3{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Object3
    {
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public string Quality { get; set; }
        public string QualityDescription { get; set; }
        public string Grid { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
    }
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Pretty noob here with C# - I was going to do it with `foreach` loops but I thought it was extremely messy.

Comment: And what is your "not the best" way and what is wrong whith it? anyway it can be done in one line with zip, select and toarray

Comment: Pretty noob here with c# - I was going to do it with foreach loops but I thought it was extremely messy

Comment: `var o3array = o1array.Zip(o2array, (o1, o2) => new o3 { ... based on data from o1 and o2 ... }).ToArray()`  (hehe select is not even requiered) ... basically `Enumerable.Zip` itereates over 2 enumerables at the same time

Comment: ahhhh that looks so much cleaner thank you for that - sorry for not being clear at the start about what I did

Comment: If I were you I'd write a static method: `public static Object3 FromObject1AndObject2(Object1 o1, Object2 o2){...}` to create the new object from the two other objects, and call THAT in a loop or from `Enumerable.Zip`. That will be more readable. (That method could of course be a local method.)

Comment: Create a constructor in `Object3` that takes a `ObjectType1` and a `ObjectType2` as arguments and fills in the properties as needed. Then use `Enumerable.Zip()` to combine the two arrays into one.

Comment: @JAlex The problem with that is that `Object3` is in the model, but `ObjectType1` and `ObjectType2` are DTOs - and you don't want to make the model dependent on a DTO.

Answer (score 2):

I think that putting the Zip and Select into one statement will make the code unneccessarily hard to read. Better to write a specific method to combine them. It's definitely appropriate to use Zip to perform the actual combining though.

I'd write a separate helper class something like this:

```
public static class Combiner
{
    public static Object3 Combine(ObjectType1 o1, ObjectType2 o2)
    {
        return new Object3
        {
            Group              = o1.Group,
            Quality            = o1.Quality,
            QualityDescription = o1.QualityDescription,
            Grid               = o2.Grid,
            Position           = o2.Position
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Object3> Combine(
        IEnumerable<ObjectType1> o1Seq,
        IEnumerable<ObjectType2> o2Seq)
    {
        return o1Seq.Zip(o2Seq, Combine);
    }

    public static ValidationResultDto CreateValidationResultDto(Class1 class1)
    {
        return new ValidationResultDto
        {
            Object3 = Combine(class1.ObjectType1, class1.ObjectType2).ToArray()
        };
    }
}
```

Obviously this is a lot more typing than just doing it inline like this:

```
public static ValidationResultDto CreateValidationResultDto(Class1 class1)
{
    return new ValidationResultDto
    {
        Object3 = class1.ObjectType1.Zip(class1.ObjectType2, (o1, o2) =>
            new Object3
            {
                Group              = o1.Group,
                Quality            = o1.Quality,
                QualityDescription = o1.QualityDescription,
                Grid               = o2.Grid,
                Position           = o2.Position
            }).ToArray()
    };
}
```

I personally find that somewhat harder to read (and therefore, to check for correctness), but that's just me.

You can choose whichever you prefer, of course.